# program crashes on closing

Tags: c, crash

So, it's my first time posting here and I will try to be as specific as I can.
I have to make a program for my school that says:

First write a function that gets a character and returns:

1. The same character if it's an upper case letter.
2. The upper case letter if it's a lower case one.
3. A backslash ('\') if it's a number.
4. An asterisk ('*') in any other case.

Then, using your function, make a program that get's a string and reprints it after it's changed by the function. It should keep asking for a new string until the user types 'QUIT', which, in that case, will print 'Bye!' and then quit.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char fnChange(char c)
{
     if (c > 'a'-1 && c < 'z'+1)
          c = c - 32;
     else if (c > '0'-1 && c < '9'+1)
          c = '\\' ;
     else if ( c > 'A'-1 && c < 'Z'+1)
          c = c;
     else 
          c = '*';
     return c;
}


int main()
{   
    int i, refPoint;
    char *str = (char*)malloc(10);
    //without the next one, the program crashes after 3 repeats.
    refPoint = str;
    while (1==1) {            
       printf("Give a string: ");
       str = refPoint;//same as the comment above.
       free(str);
       scanf("%s",str);
         if (*str == 'Q' && *(str+1) == 'U' && *(str+2) == 'I' && *(str+3) == 'T') {
           // why won't   if (str == 'QUIT')   work?
           free(str);
           printf("Bye!");     //after printing "Bye!", it crashes.
           system("pause");    //it also crashes if i terminate with ctrl+c.
           exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); //or just closing it with [x].
         }       
         printf("The string becomes: ");
         while (*str != '\0') {
           putchar(fnChange(*str));
           str++;
         }
      printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: `str = refPoint`?????

Comment: `free(str)` and then `scanf("%s",str)`????? What exactly are you expecting to happen???

Comment: A minor point (there are *real issues* with your code, see Joachim's answer below), instead of `c > 'a'-1` you really should write `c >= 'a'`. Or, even better, just use [`islower()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/islower).

Comment: `refPoint = str;`? `refPoint` is not a pointer!

Comment: "why won't   if (str == 'QUIT')   work?" - because you need functions like `strcmp()` to compare strings: `if( strcmp( str, "QUIT" ) == 0 ) { .. }`

Comment: Removing free(str) fixed the crash. But removing the whole refPoint thing made it crash again. Also, c >= 'a' wouldn't compile for a strange reason

Comment: Also, strcmp worked fine. Thanks @IngoLeonhardt. Unfortunately I'm not allowed to use functions like islower() or toupper(). The whole point is to learn about pointers and ASCII.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple reasons this can crash. In order of your code, more or less:

You `free` str and then do a scanf into it. Once you've freed memory it is no longer available for use.

Then the scanf: `scanf("%s", str)`. A soon as someone enters a string of 10 or more characters at the console, you enter the realms of undefined behaviour as memory will get overwritten.

Assigning `str` to `refpoint` and vice versa should give you loads of compiler warnings. One of your variables is an `int`, the other a `char *`. On some architectures, a pointer won't fit in an `int`, and your program will crash as soon as you use it.

Your while loop increments `str`. Without the (dangerous) copy from `refpoint` you'll end up attempting to free a pointer which was not the result of a `malloc`. This is undefined behaviour and will likely crash.

In passing:

Please don't cast the result of `malloc`. It returns a void * and in C you can assign a `void *` to anything, and unnecessary casting reduces the readability of the code. Casting implies you're doing something a little unusual, and that assignment isn't.

You can't do `str == 'QUIT`' because the C compiler will compare the address of string with - well, the effects of typing 'QUIT' are compiler dependent. It'll possibly compare it with the character value of 'Q'. Even with `str == "QUIT"` it'll compare the value of the pointer `str` (i.e. the address returned by `malloc`) with the address of the string "QUIT", which'll be wherever the linker has designed to store it. C doesn't do string comparisons, you have to use `strcmp` for that.

Answer (score 5):

```
free(str);
scanf("%s",str);
```

*Big* no-no there, you are not allowed to use dynamically allocated memory after you've freed it. On top of that, you free it *again* inside the loop.

Doing so is undefined behaviour. That's almost certainly the cause of your crash.

A couple of other issues. You can use `<=` instead of `<` to make your code more readable, such as with:

```
if  ((c >= 'a') && (c <= 'z')) ...
```

Using *magic* numbers like `32` is almost always a bad idea. Provided you're using an encoding where letters are consecutive (such as ASCII), you can do:

```
c = c - 'A' + 'a';
```

to turn uppercase into lowercase.

What you *really* should be doing however, is using `toupper()` and `tolower()` (and `isupper()` and `islower()` as well, to detect case) since the letters are *not* guaranteed to be contiguous.

The expression `str == 'QUIT'` won't do what you think because `'QUIT'` is not a string. Rather it's a multi-byte character literal. However, even `str == "QUIT"` won't do what you think since the correct way to compare strings in C is:

```
if (strcmp (str, "QUIT") == 0) ...
```

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple cases of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in your code.

First of all you assign a pointer to an integer variable. Those are not really compatible (think for example about what happens if the size of `int` is 32 bits and the size of the pointer is 64 bits).

Then you free the allocated pointer right before you use it, thereby writing to unallocated memory.

And later you call `free` on the same pointer again.